# Working with POSTed json objects in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, json

I am trying to figure out how to deal with POSTed json objects in Django.  I'm POSTing a json object to the server and want to use it like a python dictionary.

here is my js:

```
$.post(
        "/projects/vote/", 
        obj,
        function(data) {
            //alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            alert(data["msg"]);
});
```

What I am returning (end of django view):

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(foo), mimetype="application/json")
```

where

```
foo = {"msg": str(postdata)}
```

In other words, I'm POSTing a json object to the server, and alerting the string of the python object I get on the server so I can see what's going on.

If my obj is:

```
var obj = {
    'bulk': false,
    'data': {
          'chosen': '14',
          'proj1': '15',
          'proj2': '14',
          'proj3': '16',
          'more': false,


        },
    'data2': [
           {
               'a': 'apple'
           },
           {
               'b': 'banana'
           },
        ],      
  }
```

I get this in return:

```
<QueryDict: {u'data[proj3]': [u'16'], u'data[proj2]': [u'14'], u'data[chosen]': [u'14'], u'data[proj1]': [u'15'], u'bulk': [u'false'], u'data2[0][a]': [u'apple'], u'data[more]': [u'false'], u'data2[1][b]': [u'banana']}>
```

How come the structure of the json obj and python dict don't align?  And how do I get the structure to be the same? e.g. instead of data2[0][a], I would get data2 as the key to another dictionary

How I'm getting postdata:

```
# django version 1.4
postdata = request.POST.copy()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may post json as plain string using `JSON.stringify` like this:

```
    $.post(
            "/projects/vote/", 
            {msg: JSON.stringify(obj)},
            function(data) {
                //alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
                alert(data);
    });
```

Thus on server side you should just extract `'msg'` from `request.POST`:

```
    def view(request):
          return HttpResponse(request.POST['msg'], mimetype="application/json")
```

Note, that `JSON.stringify` is not supported by default in some browsers and you may want to use json lib: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score 1):

You don't show how you're getting `postdata` from the POST, but you should be using `request.body` (`request.raw_post_data` in versions before 1.4).

Answer (score 0):

You did not post JSON data. Set the `dataType` parameter to `json`:

```
$.post(
        "/projects/vote/", 
        obj,
        function(data) {
            //alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            alert(data["msg"]);
        },
        'json'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The server can simply return a string, and the js can be written like this:

```
$.post(
    "/projects/vote/", 
    obj,
    function(data) {
        data=eval('(' + data+ ')');//get the json object from string.
        //alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        alert(data["msg"]);
});
```

Hope this helpful.